# Looking for a C# cache manager

Tags: c#, asp.net, cache-control

I'm searching for a good cache manager for generic objects.

I'm using C# with ASP.NET. I want to use `System.Web.Cache`. So I want a cache manager that will care about the caching and implement functions like ADD, GET, and UPDATE.

Comment: What are you talking about..is it for asp.net... your question is too vague

Comment: in the title i wrote for c# so asp.net

Comment: Please...do not say please. The community helps itself by answering questions not by saying (please, thanks..etc etc).

Comment: Is there reasons why you don't want to use `System.Web.Cache` ? Does it need to be distributed ? You need more information and context in your question in order for it to make sense.

Comment: well Please is a polite way of asking question.. i don't see any problem in that.. the problem is in the question itself...

Comment: ok sorry mybee i was not clear ,i want to use the System.Web.Cache i'm searching for mybee good implemented cache manger

Comment: @avnic writing C# in title dosen't tell us its for ASP.Net and FYI even VB.Net can be used for ASP.Net.. ASP is just and Server side technology not a language itself... and writing ASP.Net in Tags doesn't hurt...

Comment: OK i got all your comments...but why my message edited to delete the 'thanks' in the end hahahha we are not robots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NVelocity, NCache, and the Microsoft P&P Caching block

Answer (score 2):

For in-process memory caching take a look at the following:

For .NET 4: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997357(v=VS.100).aspx

For earlier versions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c(v=vs.71).aspx

http://codemaverick.blogspot.com/2007/01/caching-in-windows-application-i-was_8639.html

Those can easily be used to cache objects, though the latter is mostly intended for caching ASP.net pages - if that's what you want :)